# C# Linq Select Problem in Method Chain

Tags: c#, linq, select, selector

Note that the _src inherit `IQueryable<U>` and V inherit `new()`;

I wrote the following statement, there is no syntax error.

```
IQueryable<V> a = from s in _src where (s.Right - 1 == s.Left) select new V();
```

But if i RE-wrote it as follows, the Visual Studio editor complains an error in the "Select"

```
IQueryable<V> d = _src.Where(s => s.Right - 1 == s.Left).Select(s=> new V());
```

The Error is:

```
The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
Candidates are:
  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<V> Select<U,V>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<U>, System.Func<U,V>) (in class Enumerable)
  System.Linq.IQueryable<V> Select<U,V>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<U>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<U,V>>) (in class Queryable)
```

Could anyone explain this phenomenon, and what the solution is to fix the error?

**=== Edit (2010-03-16 5:35pm) ===**

Thanks Mike Two. I also tried a simple example like you. It works but this does not do in mine. I posted the code as follows:

```
public class NSM<U, V> where U : IQueryable<U> where V : new()  
  {
    private U _src;
    public NSM(U source) { _src = source; }
    public IQueryable<V> LeafNodes
    {
      get
        {
          return from s in _src where (s.Right - 1 == s.Left) select new V();
        }
    }
  }
```

I want the LeafNodes function to be rewritten into linq method chain method. Any Idea?

Comment: Thanks all. What is the equivalent statement of the first?

Comment: That code you added won't compile unless U is something that has a Right and Left property. So it can't just be an `IQueryable<U>` unless there is a `where U : ILeftRight` or something.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to your updated sample. See updated answer below. Thanks for providing more information.

Comment: Thanks all. The solution works and the example clearly clarifies the problem. By the way, What the difference between Expression<Func<X,V>> and Func<X,V>? The type of "x => new V()" could be either of them?

Comment: Yes `x => new V()` could be either a `Func<X,V>` or an `Expression<Func<X,V>>`. `IQueryable` implemenations can inspect the contents of the `Expression` version and interpret them as needed. It is how LINQ to SQL changes lambdas to SQL queries. For a better explaination see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of _src? Does it directly implement IQueryable? I ask because I can get a simplified example of what you are showing to work.

```
IQueryable< int > ints = Enumerable.Range( 4, 12 ).AsQueryable();

IQueryable< decimal > foo = from s in ints where s > 7 select s * 4.2m;

IQueryable< decimal > bar = ints.Where( s => s > 7 ).Select( s => s * 4.2m );
```

Both of those selects work for me. I think if the compiler knows that ints (or in your case _src) is an IQueryable then it will call the right overload. Or am I completely missing something? Perhaps I oversimplified it and lost a bit of detail.

EDIT: Extending this to use the new sample code with some changes.

The trick is that `Queryable.Select` takes an `Expression<Func<X, V>>` and `Enumerable.Select` takes a `Func<X,V>` So you just need to provide an `Expression` version to `Select`

```
public interface ILeftRight
{
    int Right { get;}
    int Left { get; }
}

public class NSM<X, U, V> where U : IQueryable<X> where X : ILeftRight where V : new()  
{
    private readonly U _src;
    public NSM(U source) { _src = source; }
    public IQueryable<V> LeafNodes
    {
        get
        {
            //return from s in _src where (s.Right - 1 == s.Left) select new V();
            Expression< Func< X, V > > expression = s => new V();
            return _src.Where( s => s.Right - 1 == s.Left ).Select( expression );
        }
    }
}
```

Or from the original code

```
Expression<Func<X,V>> expression = s => new V();
IQueryable<V> d = _src.Where(s => s.Right - 1 == s.Left).Select(expression);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurres because compiler cannot choose what methods you want to be executed: `Select` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` or `Select` extension method for `IQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that there are 2 different uses for Select in your second example, and you have the appropriate using statement to get to both of them. The compiler can not figure out from that statement which one you want to use.  You either have to use a more specialized call to Select or remove a using if it is no longer needed, or in some other way clarify which one you want to use.

Comment: If i add "AsQueryable()" to the Select as follows:

IQueryable<V> d = _src.Where(s => s.Right - 1 == s.Left).AsQueryable().Select(s=> new V());

The error also is the same.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the ambiguity for the compiler use the `AsEnumerable()` function

```
src.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new V());
```

Or to assign to IQueryable

```
IQueryable<V> x = src.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new V()).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: But this would return IEnumerable<V> rather than IQueryable<V>. What's the fix without changing the return type?